# Yates' continuity correction in confidence interval returned by prop.test

Tags: r, confidence-interval, yates-correction

This is the confidence interval estimated by prop.test

```
n <- 600; x <- 276; p <- 0.40
prop.test(x, n, p, alternative="two.sided", conf.level=0.95, correct=T)
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4196787 0.5008409
```

I tried to reproduce it, reading the code under prop.test. Here is a simplified way to get those two limits

```
ESTIMATE <- x/n
YATES <- 0.5
conf.level <- 0.95
z <- qnorm((1 + conf.level)/2)
YATES <- min(YATES, abs(x - n * p)) 
z22n <- z^2/(2 * n)
p.c <- ESTIMATE + YATES/n
(p.c + z22n + z * sqrt(p.c * (1 - p.c)/n + z22n/(2 * n)))/(1 + 2 * z22n)
[1] 0.5008409
p.c <- ESTIMATE - YATES/n
(p.c + z22n - z * sqrt(p.c * (1 - p.c)/n + z22n/(2 * n)))/(1 + 2 * z22n)
[1] 0.4196787
```

Can you explain to me why the underlying probability of success (p) is used in line 5? or maybe you could suggest where can I find more info about this YATES correction that affects the ESTIMATE.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help page indicates that "Continuity correction is used only if it does not exceed the difference between sample and null proportions in absolute value." This is what line 5 is checking: `x/n` is the empirical proportion, `p` is the null proportion. (Actually, I find the "if" slightly misleading since it's more of a "insofar as it does not exceed" when looking at line 5.)

Answer (score 7):

On the second question of where you can find more info on this continuity correction (attributed to Yates in the help for `prop.test` but not in the refs below, I think [as Yates orginally proposed a continuity correction only to the chi-squared test for contingency tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27_correction_for_continuity)):

1. Newcombe RG. Two-sided confidence intervals for the single proportion: comparison of seven methods. Stat Med 1998; 17(8):857-872. PMID:[9595616](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9595616)
2. Brown LD, Cai TT, DasGupta A. Interval estimation for a binomial proportion (with Comments &  Rejoinder). Statistical Science 2001; 16(2):101-133. doi:[10.1214/ss/1009213286](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1214/ss/1009213286)

The continuity-corrected Wilson score interval is 'method 4' in Newcomb. Brown et al. consider only the uncorrected Wilson score interval in the main text, but George Casella suggests using the continuity-corrected version in his Comment (p121), which Brown et al. discuss in their Rejoinder (p130):

> Casella suggests the possibility of performing
>   a continuity correction on the score statistic
>   prior to constructing a confidence interval. We do
>   not agree with this proposal from any perspective.
>   These “continuity-corrected Wilson” intervals
>   have extremely conservative coverage properties,
>   though they may not in principle be guaranteed to
>   be everywhere conservative. But even if one’s goal,
>   unlike ours, is to produce conservative intervals,
>   these intervals will be very inefficient at their normal
>   level relative to Blyth–Still or even Clopper–
>   Pearson.

The Clopper-Pearson 'exact' interval is provided by `binom.test` in R. I'd suggest using that rather than `prop.test` if you want a conservative interval, i.e. one that guarantees *at least* 95% coverage. If you'd prefer an interval that has close to 95% coverage *on average* (over p) and will therefore often be narrower, you could use `prop.test(…, correct=FALSE)` to give the uncorrected Wilson score interval.

The standard textbook for such matters is Fleiss *Statistical Methods for Rates and Proportions*. Newcomb references the original 1981 edition but [the latest edition is the 3rd (2003)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a5LwdxF2d10C). I haven't checked it myself, however.

Comment: Another reference for the comparison of binomial CIs is Brown LD, Cai TT, & DasGupta, A. (2001). Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion. Statistical Science, 16(2), 101-133. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213286 (open access). R's `binom` package also has the Agresti-Coull CI.