# How to calculate confidence interval for count data in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, count-data

As question, I have found something similar [here](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ConfInterval1.cfm), but how to do it in R?

Comment: Is the example at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5206/919 helpful?

Comment: `poisson.test` gives identical answers to the page that you pointed to for count data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for a confidence interval around the count from a Poisson process.  If you put for example 42 into your linked example you get

> You observed 42 objects in a certain
>   volume or 42 events in a certain time
>   period.
>
> Exact Poisson confidence interval:
>
> - The 90% confidence interval extends from 31.94 to 54.32
> - The 95% confidence interval extends from 30.27 to 56.77
> - The 99% confidence interval extends from 27.18 to 61.76

You can get this in R using `poisson.test`.  For example

```
> poisson.test(42, conf.level = 0.9 )

        Exact Poisson test

data:  42 time base: 1 
number of events = 42, time base = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true event rate is not equal to 1 
90 percent confidence interval:
 31.93813 54.32395 
sample estimates:
event rate 
        42
```

and similarly the other values by changing `conf.level`.  If you do not want all the background information, try something like

```
> poisson.test(42, conf.level = 0.95 )$conf.int
[1] 30.26991 56.77180
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Answer (score 6):

If the number of event is too small, it would be better to use the exact method.

```
exactPoiCI <- function (X, conf.level=0.95) {
  alpha = 1 - conf.level
  upper <- 0.5 * qchisq((1-(alpha/2)), (2*X))
  lower <- 0.5 * qchisq(alpha/2, (2*X +2))
  return(c(lower, upper))
}
exactPoiCI(42, 0.9)
exactPoiCI(42)
exactPoiCI(42, 0.99)
```

Reference: Liddell FD. Simple exact analysis of the standardised mortality ratio. J Epidemiol Community Health. 1984;38:85-8 ([link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1052324/))

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you mind expanding upon this. What exactly does "count data is too small" mean (sample size small or intensity of events is too small?) A reference would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer using poisson.test does give the exact confidence interval. However, this calculation is so simple that I prefer to calculate it directly instead of using a library function. In the second answer, there is a minor error. The +2 should be in the degree of freedom for the upper CI calculation, not for the lower one. So the correct code should be:

```
exactPoiCI <- function (X, conf.level=0.95) {
  alpha = 1 - conf.level
  upper <- 0.5 * qchisq(1-alpha/2, 2*X+2)
  lower <- 0.5 * qchisq(alpha/2, 2*X)
  return(c(lower, upper))
}

exactPoiCI(42, 0.9)
exactPoiCI(42)
exactPoiCI(42, 0.99)
```

Comment: But this is already present in the other answer. Why did you put this here?

Comment: The other answer had an error, this is a correction. Note the +2 is in the upper CI calculation.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for correcting the error.