# How to get confidence intervals for Patient-Years?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, biostatistics, medicine

In medicine patient-years is a popular concept. Example: $100$ patients are followed for $2$ years. In this case, there are $200$ patient-years in total.
If there were $8$ myocardial infarctions in the group, the rate would be $8$ MIs per $200$ patient years or $8/200*100= 4$ MIs per $100$ patient-years or  $8/200*1000= 40$ per $1,000$ patient years, and so on (see [here](http://delfini.org/blog/?p=612)).

See [here](http://www.copd-international.com/SpirivaPR5-23.html) for an example where confidence intervals are reported for patient years:

> For MGUS patients we estimated a mortality rate of 52 [95% CI 48-56] per 1000 patient-years, whereas for MGRS patients the rate was 29 [14-58] per 1000 patient-years.

How can I get CI for patient-years like this?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @EdM for the great answer. There are two problems:

1. **I get other results**. The [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/how-to-calculate-confidence-interval-for-count-data-in-r/10929#10929) in the answer suggests to use the Poisson distribution with `poisson.test`. Doing so for the results above gives me for example:

`poisson.test(52, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int`

38.84 to 68.19. But in the source above it is 52 [95% CI 48-56]

2. **The results differ depending on what time frame the rate refers to**. For example, if we choose mortality rate per 10,000 patient years instead the CI's change. For mortality rate per 1,000 patient years the CI's overlap (52[38.84-68.19] and 29[19.42-41.65]). For the morality rate per 10,000 patient years the CI's don't overlap (520[476.26-566.68] and 290[257.58-325.37]).

Comment: The first reference you quote is not about comparing patient years (py) but about comparing incidence rates (number per py). Perhaps that is the key search term you are looking for?

Comment: @mdewey I edited the question and added the text. The 2nd source also seems to refer to a rate, namely the mortality rate. But they report the results for "per 1000 patient-years" and this is something I don't understand. So I wonder how to get a value with the CI for py.

Comment: "I get other results." I don't think your calculation makes sense here (/possible at all), because you don't know how many person-years they had! You only know the rate. What you did (`T=1` is the default in `poisson.test`!) essentially assumes 1 py with 52 deaths. If they had 520 deaths in 10 py (`poisson.test( 520, T = 10 )`) then the point estimate for the rate is the same (so both is possible), yet the CI is different.

Comment: By the way it is rather easy to figure out what *could have been* the py: `round( sapply( 1:20, function( x ) poisson.test( 52*x, T = x )$conf.int ), 0 )`, so 11 to 15 is possible.

Comment: "The results differ depending on what time frame the rate refers to." Yes, that is just the solution to your question (see above). It is totally logical: more py is analogous to having higher sample size, so of course the sampling variability is lower.

Comment: @TamasFerenci For my udnerstanding: If we knew that the authors observed 13 deaths in 250 py (which gives a rate of 52 per 1,000 py), then we could do `poisson.test(13, T=250)` to get the CI? So my mistake is to use the rate instead of the actual number of death and the actual amount of py?

Comment: @schwantke Yes, exactly! What you originally ran was the same as `poisson.test(52,T=1)`.

Comment: @TamasFerenci Alright! You wrote "so 11 to 15 is possible...". If I get it right the following gives CI's for those possible values.. `sapply(11:15, function(x){
  py <- 1000 / (52/x)
  poisson.test(x, T=py)$conf.int[1:2]})`

Comment: @TamasFerenci Okay, now I now I am not supposed to use the rate but the original data (number of deaths and py observed). But how did the authors manage to give a CI for the rate? That is what the question is actually about since py is always a rate.

Comment: "If I get it right the following gives CI's for those possible values" Yes, it works as well, but the range is wrong: here you give the number of deaths, so it should be from 600 to 800 roughly.

Comment: "But how did the authors manage to give a CI for the rate?" They knew the number of deaths (e.g. 650) and the follow-up time (e.g. 12,500 py), and put those in: `poisson.test(650,12500)` and voilá!

Comment: What is interesting however, is that my above calculation shows that the py should be between 11,000 and 15,000, yet they say: `Overall follow-up time for the 2935 patients was 11,050 person-years`, so it seems that the *overall* is close to the number that we would need in the MGUS group (that's where we had 52 [95% CI 48-56]). I don't the the explanation for this...

Comment: @TamasFerenci Thank you so much!! So all they had to do with their original data was to put in `poisson.test(650,12500)` and to multiply the output by 1,000 because they wanted to report events per 1,000 py. Now I got it!

Comment: @schwantke Yes, exactly!!

Comment: Ah, I think I got it: almost everyone was in the MGUS group! That's the explanation (2,891 in the MGUS group and only 44 in the MGRS). So it is okay that almost all follow-up time is in the MGUS group.

Comment: Just as a final check: `for MGRS patients the rate was 29 [14-58] per 1000 patient-years` - it makes it clear that in the MGRS group they didn't even had a *single* py of follow-up. So everything checks.

Comment: "they didn't even had a single py of follow-up" Sorry, I means single 1000py.

Comment: @schwantke I simply iterated on the possible follow-up times (in 1000 py). Then, the number of deaths must be 52 times the follow-up time, so that the rate - which is the number of deaths divided by the follow-up time - is 52, as in the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They indeed used Poisson distribution ("We calculated crude incidence rates as the number of events divided by the total number of person-years at risk following MGUS diagnosis, and 95% confidence intervals (CIs) were based on a Poisson distribution").

We can infer the likely follow-up times: `round( sapply( 1:20, function( x ) poisson.test( 52*x, T = x )$conf.int ), 0 )` so something between 11,000 and 15,000 seems to work for the MGUS group (where we had a mortality rate of 52 [95% CI 48-56] per 1000 patient-years), and `round( sapply( seq( 0.1, 1, 0.1 ), function( x ) poisson.test( round( 29*x ), T = x )$conf.int ), 0 )` suggests around 300 py (where the rate was 29 [14-58] per 1000 patient-years).

This seems extremely unbalanced, but so was the sample: they had 2,891 MGUS and 44 MGRS patients. They write that "Overall follow-up time for the 2935 patients was 11,050 person-years" so everything seems to check.

UPDATE: AAh, this whole calculation was unnecessary: they've given the number of deaths! "Of the 2891 MGUS patients 566 (20%) and of the 44 MGRS patients eight (18%) died during follow-up." So we actually *know* the follow-up time (up to rounding): $566/52=10.9$ in the MGUS group, $8/29=0.28$ in the MGRS (in 1000 py). `poisson.test(566,10.9)` and `poisson.test(8,0.28)` checks basically OK (I mean the CIs match the presented ones, with a little difference in the MGRS group), and $10.9+0.28= 11.18$ also checks out more-or-less with their presented overall follow-up time.

(I don't know what is the reason for the difference in the MGRS group; I checked that no follow-up time for which the rate is rounded to 29 will result in the CI they presented in the paper. Perhaps its just a rounding error on their part; my best idea is to write an email to the corresponding author.)

Comment: Thank you so much! "We can infer the likely follow-up times". Why is the rate multiplied by a number and this number used as the T value to get the possible range? Somehow I don't understand the logic behind that.

Comment: @schwantke  I simply iterated on the possible follow-up times (in 1000 py). Then, the number of deaths must be 52 times the follow-up time, so that the rate - which is the number of deaths divided by the follow-up time - is 52, as in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Events per patient-year are calculated as the number of events divided by the number of patient-years. As the number of patient-years is known, the source of variability is in the number of counts.

Infrequent events like those in these studies are often analyzed as if they are sampled from a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). For a Poisson distribution, the mean and the variance are equal so that [confidence intervals and p-values can be calculated just from the number of events](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10929/28500). There should, however, be some effort made to document that the Poisson model is appropriate for the data set. If time-to-event information is important, then a more complete [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) should be performed.

I suspect that the "exacerbation days" were modeled as continuous variables with comparisons done with *t*-tests, although the details aren't clear from the page you linked. Similar considerations would still apply: the number of patient-years is known, so the variability is simply in the distributions of "exacerbation days" between treatment and control groups.